# Using OS 6 fig grid refs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, united-kingdom, ordnance-survey

I have a large (>4,000 points) dataset of species records that needs to be mapped in QGIS, however the only spatial information with them are 6 figure OS grid references (eg SD311124). The file is csv.

How can I get QGIS to plot the points with this information?

Is there a better way to do it within QGIS rather than bulk converting and adding lat/long coords to the spreadsheet before loading it into QGIS?

Comment: Did you do a simple google search for "convert csv os grid to lat long"? E.g.this: https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/csv-to-gps

Answer (score 0):

do you need to convert to Lat/Long?

If not the Tom Bio biological records tool can convert your grid references from your csv. Point it at your csv, identify the grid ref column and species name column (Taxon column), then choose if you want your grids represented as points or squares. When you've made your selections click the button in the bottom left hand corner to turn your records in to a map

[image]

If you do need them as lat long, then there is a batch converter at
https://gridreferencefinder.com/batchConvert/batchConvert.php

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for general CSV